# Debugging a library built in release mode

Tags: c++, debugging, cout

I have a library that needs to be built in Release Mode with Debug Info for reasons out of my control.

I have an executable to run unit tests that links to a dynamic build of the library.

I tried using breakpoints to debug the code but step by step won't go into methods defined in the library. I then tried to write to `std::cerr` and `std::cout`, flushing or not flushing but I can't see the statements in the console when running the unit tests, even when passing `--verbose`.

How can I get std::cerr/out to work or is there a third way to debug the library I am not seeing?

Comment: Using breakpoints and stepping can be tricky in release mode code. In Visual Studio I mostly end up in going to disassembly to make sure a function is stepped into. Ofc you still need one breakpoint to be fired around the call site.

Comment: Can you get code inside a library built in release mode to print to standard error or output?

Comment: if you have the source code and your application is a console program I would think so.

Comment: If you don't have access to the source code library, you probably can't debug it at all.

Comment: I have access to the source code, I just can't see the output of writing to std::cerr. Maybe googletest is swallowing that?

Comment: Try to use [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) and [`OutputDebugString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-ch/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa)

Answer (score 0):

So basically I wasn't copying a new version of the shared library to the test executable directory when I executed my tests.